# Unity's inspector shows "Type mismatch" on serialized field when this isn't true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Long story short, I have two lists that are both serialized so I can track them in Unity's inspector. One list is a copy of the other but appears as a type mismatch when I look at them in the inspector.

The first one is called realRoomObjects, which I put in the values for before running. The second one is a copy of the first called roomObjects. Despite the code working fine, this shows up as type mismatch in the inspector.

This is the function I use to clone (it's called on start by another object)

```
// realRoomObjects is what the game starts with but the issue is that the game alters objects permanently.
// Therefore, realRoomObjects is copied into roomObjects 
[SerializeField] List<RoomObject> realRoomObjects;
[SerializeField] List<RoomObject> roomObjects;

public void prepareRoomObjects()
{
    roomObjects = new List<RoomObject>();
    foreach (RoomObject obj in realRoomObjects)
    {
        RoomObject temp = Instantiate(obj);
        temp.name = obj.name;
        roomObjects.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image showing inspector. List 1 is shown with 3 objects normally, List 2 shows 3 "Type Mismatch" objects.]

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it (assuming it's not a bug in Unity itself)?

Note: RoomObject is a Scriptable Object. I also tried using `CreateInstance()` but got the same result.

Comment: Ether update your 2 list in OnValidate or dont serialize it at all, why do you want to have both showing up in the inspector, if the second is just a copy of the first one

Comment: Please include a [mre].